# Common limit for infinity derivation(reciprocal?)

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I really don't know what to call the somewhat reciprocal of a common limit but it has a form of:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{k}\right)^x$$

I know the original version of it:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{k}{x}\right)^x$$

has a value of $$e^k,$$ I know how to derive this as well. The problem is to derive the first equation. I know it's supposed to have an answer of:
$$\frac{1}{e^k}$$

During my derivation I somehow end up with:

$$\ln(y)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^2}{k+x}$$

which is wrong(I think) can someone please guide me through this

Comment: @PeterForeman, sorry used the wrong variable haha

Comment: What makes you think this limit converges?

Comment: @PeterForeman  I am quite not sure why but my professor gave an answer to a similar  problem. His answer had a form of 1/e^k , he said that this was the answer because it was the reciprocal of the common limit of infinite sequences, which would have an answer of e^k

Comment: What you have written is clearly different from the reciprocal of the common limit.

Answer (score 1):

We have that for $x\ge2k$

$$\left(1+\frac{x}{k}\right)^x\ge\left(\frac{x}{k}\right)^x\ge2^x \to \infty $$

The result you are looking for involves the following limit

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{k}{x}\right)^x=e^{-k}=\frac1{e^k}$$

Comment: Yep, the problem is how I can derive that 1/e^k

Comment: @Monsi Then we only need $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{a}{x}\right)^x=e^a$$ with $a=-k$.